# xslTransform.Transform to XslCompiledTransform.Transform

Tags: xml, .net, c#

Hi I am clearing all warnings in my application, I used below code in my application

```
      DataSet dsBillItem = new DataSet();
      System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator xNav = xmlResponse.CreateNavigator();
      XslTransform xslTransform = new XslTransform();
      xslTransform.Load("test.xslt");
      XmlReader xmlReader = xslTransform.Transform(xNav, null);
      dsBillItem.ReadXml(xmlReader);
```

"XslTransform" showing warning as "This class has been deprecated. Please use System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform instead. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202".

If I change my code to "XslCompiledTransform", its throwing error on this line "XmlReader xmlReader = xslTransform.Transform(xNav, null);". Reason is this Transform method available only with void return type.

Please help me anyone on this, any code for xslt file to dataset conversion or any other way is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`Transform(IXPathNavigable, XsltArgumentList, Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163434%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload method, and use `MemoryStream` to create `XmlReader` :

```
.....
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

// Load the style sheet.
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load("test.xslt");
// Execute the transformation.
xslt.Transform(xNav, null, stream);

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);    
.....
```